# Como identificar atualizações no servidor com Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, service-worker, pwa

É possível identificar que houve atualização no servidor, ou seja, houve atualização na página (HTML) ou no estilo (CSS), e fazer a requisição para o servidor para buscar os dados atualizados? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pergunta interessante. Já tentou usar um timestamp no nome dos scripts? Isso ajudaria na hora que ocorre uma atualização.

Dá uma olhada no https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/2015/service-workers-iowa#stale-content

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraços!